# Using mutate_if and replace_na to replace all results based on a condition

Tags: r

I have a dataset similar to the `mtcars` dataset.

```
                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat  wt qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4            21   6  160 110  3.9 2.6   16  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag        21   6  160 110  3.9 2.9   17  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710           23   4  108  93  3.9 2.3   19  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive       21   6  258 110  3.1 3.2   19  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout    19   8  360 175  3.1 3.4   17  0  0    3    2
Valiant              18   6  225 105  2.8 3.5   20  1  0    3    1
```

I want to replace all rows based on some condition. i.e. `mpg > 20` and `cyl = 6` so it Will return.

```
                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat  wt qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4            NA  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA  NA NA  NA   NA
Mazda RX4 Wag        NA  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA  NA NA  NA   NA
Datsun 710           23   4  108  93  3.9 2.3   19  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive       NA  NA  NA   NA  NA   NA  NA  NA NA  NA   NA
Hornet Sportabout    19   8  360 175  3.1 3.4   17  0  0    3    2
Valiant              18   6  225 105  2.8 3.5   20  1  0    3    1
```

Additionally I would like to only replace certain columns with NAs based on the same condition. That is, only replace the columns `disp.`, `hp` and `drat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with the recently release `across` functionality (version `>= 1.0.0`):

```
mymtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  mutate(across(c(disp, hp, drat),
                ~ if_else(mpg > 20 & cyl == 6, NA_real_, as.numeric(.))))
#                car mpg cyl disp  hp drat  wt qsec vs am gear carb
#1         Mazda RX4  21   6   NA  NA   NA 2.6   16  0  1    4    4
#2     Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6   NA  NA   NA 2.9   17  0  1    4    4
#3        Datsun 710  23   4  108  93  3.9 2.3   19  1  1    4    1
#4    Hornet 4 Drive  21   6   NA  NA   NA 3.2   19  1  0    3    1
#5 Hornet Sportabout  19   8  360 175  3.1 3.4   17  0  0    3    2
#6           Valiant  18   6  225 105  2.8 3.5   20  1  0    3    1
```

The trickiest part here is that some of the columns are double and some are integers, so you have to do something to make sure that both types of columns can be handled by the same function.

**Sample Data**

```
mymtcars <- structure(list(mpg = c(21L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 19L, 18L), cyl = c(6L, 
6L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 6L), disp = c(160L, 160L, 108L, 258L, 360L, 225L
), hp = c(110L, 110L, 93L, 110L, 175L, 105L), drat = c(3.9, 3.9, 
3.9, 3.1, 3.1, 2.8), wt = c(2.6, 2.9, 2.3, 3.2, 3.4, 3.5), qsec = c(16L, 
17L, 19L, 19L, 17L, 20L), vs = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), am = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), gear = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L), carb = c(4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Mazda RX4", 
"Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", 
"Valiant"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a few columns to do this with, you could just use `ifelse`, with a temporary logical column.

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(newcol = mpg > 20 & cyl == 6, disp = ifelse(newcol, NA, disp), 
         hp = ifelse(newcol, NA, hp),  drat = ifelse(newcol, NA, drat)) %>%
  select(-newcol)
#>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1  21.0   6    NA  NA   NA 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2  21.0   6    NA  NA   NA 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 4  21.4   6    NA  NA   NA 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> 7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> 8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> 9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> 10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> 11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> 12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
... etc
```